# Extra .SAS suffix added to file name when running SAS through shell script

Tags: linux, sas

Getting a weird error in Unix Bash. 
Might anybody have an idea what is going on?
I run a shell like this:

```
nohup sas -sysin dir/program1.sas
```

and it comes up with an error like this:

```
ERROR: Invalid file, dir/program1.sas.sas.
```

Why does it add an extra suffix `.sas.`?

It does not happen when I just paste the code into a Putty window though.

Comment: What do you mean you "run a shell like this"? How is that action different then pasting the code into Putty? Do you mean you have that in a script?

Comment: This does not appear to be a shell problem; rather, `sas` is appending the suffix. What does the `sas` documentation tell you how the `-sysin` option works?

Comment: _"weird error in Unix Bash"_ ... `bash` **is** the shell. `sas` is something, but it's not the shell; and your message `ERROR: Invalid file, dir/program1.sas.sas.` looks to me like it's coming from `sas`, not from the shell. (so it's not bash that is adding an unnecessary suffix)  Maybe _sas_ wants `dir/program1` and assumes the `.sas` suffix itself.

Comment: `.sas.` isn't the suffix, `.sas` is.  The extra `.` is just the end of the sentence.  It's also not being added by bash, it's being added by `sas`.

Comment: Try just running the command like this: `nohup sas -sysin dir/program1`. I expect that the sas executable is appending the `.sas` suffix itself which is causing the error.

Comment: Keeping the ".sas" is correct, according to the [SAS Documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostunx/61879/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000313320.htm).

Comment: And @CVer, SAS is a programming language, and as such this question is entirely on topic here.

Comment: @OP: Are you saying that you have written a shell script that contains the above, and when you execute that shell script, you get the above error?  Is it an error in your SAS log, or in your unix terminal?  Can you paste the entire contents (edited for privacy as needed) of the shell script file and either the SAS log or the terminal output?

Comment: When you paste the command into Putty it works fine?  So you only get the error when you run the same command through a shell script?  If that's it, I like @Tom's suggestion of checking the script file for unprintable characters.

Answer (score 2):

That is the normal error message when SAS cannot find the file specified. Examples:

```
 > sas unknown
 ERROR: Invalid file, unknown.sas.
 > sas unknown.sas
 ERROR: Invalid file, unknown.sas.
```

The strange part is that SAS is treating the `.sas` suffix as if it was part of the filename, instead of recognizing it. Are you sure that you do not have some hidden characters in there that do not show up when echoed to the screen?  Perhaps a backspace or cursor movement character?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
Had to do with the text file's encoding.

Here's how it worked:
1). Create a new variable in Unix vi editor
2). Paste these lines into it:
"
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
nohup sas -sysin dir/program1.sas &
nohup sas -sysin dir/program2.sas &
nohup sas -sysin dir/program3.sas ;
"

Now I can chain the programs to run in parallel and in sequence.

Thank you.